# how to add water mark on images in angular js?

Tags: angular, angularjs, watermark

I tried ngx-watermark but its only working on text node. Not working on image. And watermarkJS which is not supportive for angular Js.  I want apply "watermark image" on a image. how to achieve that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the image water mark npm i image-watermark and try the below code.

```html
var watermark = require('image-watermark');
 
watermark.embedWatermark('\home\user\sample.jpg', {'text' : 'sample watermark'});
```

Refer this link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-watermark

Comment: Thanks for your time. I added water mark in php api file instead in angular. Thank you.